# Python: numpy.ndarray object not callable error for root-finding function

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out how to use Python to find roots. If I'm understanding the documentation correctly, scipy.optimize.newton(f,x_o) can be used to find roots, f is a function and x_o an initial guess at the root.

The functions I'm working with are all polynomials and for the purposes I've ever used Python for (interpolation and line-fitting) it's always been sufficient to express a polynomial by an array of coefficients. Defining f in this manner gives me a numpy.ndarray error and I'm assuming it's because I'm giving f as an array and newton(f,x_o) is expecting a function for f.

I'm pretty inexperienced with Python and when I came across this I realized I actually don't know how to define generally f without having to define another variable that'll limit it to an interval. For some arbitrary polynomial, e.g. f = 2x^2 + 7, is there a way to define f without having to give an interval for x? Normally I'm used to having to also define x = arange(n) or something like that which limits it to an interval.

Comment: You can simply use [`numpy.poly1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html#numpy.poly1d) to make a callable out of your coefficient array.

Comment: I never knew about this. Thank you, this works just fine.

Comment: And perhaps using the function [`numpy.roots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) that is dedicated to polynomial roots would even give less headache.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the error is because of the form of `f`. If you take a look at the scipy documentation for the newton function (here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html), you can see that you have to provide a function `f(x,a,b,c)` with `a,b,c` as arguments.

if you then provide a function

```
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

and then call the newton method as follows:

```
root = scipy.optimize.newton(f, x0, args=(a, b, c))
```

the variable `root` will contain the approximate location of the root of your function. Of course you will have to provide values for the parameters `a,b,c` before you call the method.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: How do you get around not defining x through this method? This was what my initial thought was too, but I couldn't get around not defining x. I tried defining f(x) (I just chose func = cosh(x)) and then doing just as you did to call newton's method, but it gives me an error telling me that x isn't defined.

Comment: hmm... I used scipy.optimize.minimize. There you just call the function `f` without the argument, as above. Normally the scipy engine should take care of the value `x` in the function `f`. That is as much as I know...

Comment: Hmm. Trying scipy.optimize.root gives me the same problem in having to define x. I like your idea since it let's me use functions that aren't polynomials, but I can't seem to get around the x value. I'll see if I can find an alternative function that gets around having to define x.

Comment: For completion: how do you call the root function? `scipy.optimize.root(f, x0, args=(a,b,c))` should be the correct way. Even if your function is defined as `f(x, a,b,c)`, call it just with its name in the root function.